# a graph,chart component for classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, graph, charts

Can anyone recommend a graph,chart component for classic ASP. Free or not free is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fusion Charts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/ASP/?BannerSource=HotScriptsASPListing) looks promising.

Comment: I agree, Fusion Charts is awsome. I use it and it amazes users.

Comment: Fusion Charts is not component, is it?

Answer (score 2):

Google Charts. [Click here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fapis%2Fchart%2F&ei=uMZ-S5TVOIWyswO0_dT8Cw&usg=AFQjCNHtD_XG9n06lyu6yjyEmnzMYTh1LA&sig2=Nsx_EeWzZjjjpahYivNqQg).

ASP or JSP, you can use them wherever if it satisfies.

Answer (score 1):

I have used ChartFX in the past. http://www.softwarefx.com/sfxNetProducts/ChartFX/

They used to be pricey, not sure these days.

Overall great commercial charting package.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use one of the sever front end javascript graphing libraries. I've used several over the years but I like the following one because it allows data to be acquired dynamically from any server side process. In your case you would configure this to pull data directly from your ASP scripts:-

[Active Graphs and Charts](http://jpowered.com/graph_chart_collection/index.htm)